# Statistical tests to improve questionnaire

Tags: inference, survey, bias

My team run a questionnaire a year ago to collect information about commuting attitudes and preferences. As you understand, the questionnaire consists mostly of categorical and ordinal questions, and some questions using the likert scale. The team is thinking to rerun the questionnaire to collect more recent data.

I want to know if there is some kind of analysis or statistical tests I can do to analyze the questionnaire to find ways improve the questions and performance of the questionnaire.

For example, I had a quick look and I found that from all the respondents, the age group 65+ is twice as large comparing to the 16-20, 20-25 and so on. Is this something I can test, such as if the sample is representative, or if there is skewness because of the 65+ age group? Is there a statistical test that can indicate the appropriate sample size we need?